# How to iterate over the value of an object model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 objects **Weeklyactivity** and **Weeklyfood**. Weeklyactivity has property called **food_id**. and **Weeklyfood** has 7 properties called **mon, tue, ..., sun**.

When the user click update weekly food, the action method retrieves daily activity for a given week. It also retrieve all the weeklyfood object, which contains the **id** of food ate by the user every day of that week.

```
Weeklyactivities = Weeklyactivity.where(:week => wk)
@weeklyfood = Weeklyfood.New(forms[:weeklyfood])
```

Now I'd like to iterate over weeklyfood and transfert its data, which contains the id of the food the user ate each day of the week.

I don't know if this is the right way to do it or even if there is a compact way of writing this code.

```
Weeklyactivities[:day => 'mon'].food_id = @weeklyfood[:mon]
Weeklyactivities[:day => 'tue'].food_id = @weeklyfood[:tue]
//and son ...
```

## EDIT

I'm getting the following error: **"can't convert Hash into Integer..."**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question.

You have a model `Weeklyactivity` that has attributes `week` and `day` (and others)?

And according to your code example you have already created rows in the database for all days in a week for `Weeklyactivity`?

Now you want to update these rows from a form?

In that case I have this suggestion:

```
@weeklyfood = Weeklyfood.New(forms[:weeklyfood])
Weeklyactivity.where(:week => wk).each do |weekly_activity|
  if food_id = @weeklyfood[weekly_activity.day.to_sym]
    weekly_activity.food_id = food_id
    unless weekly_activity.save
      # do stuff if not successful
      break
    end
  end
end
```

And I think your objects `Weeklyactivity` and `Weeklyfood` should be named `WeeklyActivity` and `WeeklyFood` with tables respectively `weekly_activities` and `weekly_foods`

Comment: I not only solved the problem, I also learned a lot. Thanks very much.

Comment: You're welcome, I think also that you can use the little shorter `@weeklyfood[weekly_activity.day]` instead of `@weeklyfood[weekly_activity.day.to_sym]`, but I wanted to be sure that it should work.